# display the select selectAll copy cut ... in other language

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, copy-paste

with the answers of some questions I have changed the "Localization native development region" with "China" but when I debugged the app the text of the buttons just I have listed in the title are still in English Any other things I should do to solve the question?

Comment: Have you tried changing the simulator's language from the Settings app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Localizing the Cut|Copy|Paste menu on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224969/localizing-the-cutcopypaste-menu-on-ios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that:

1. change Localization native development region;
2. in the `Project->info->localization` and Add which language you need.